# android programming question

Tags: android

```
dy_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "\5.jpg";
```

Instead of that i want how to give dynamic path automatically picture saved based on current time.

I am new to Android. Plz answer my question

Comment: You probably have `"\\5.jpg"` in your code :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the path with

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
```

That is, use something like

```
String time = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
dy_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "\\" + time + "\\5.jpg";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/your folder name" + File.separator);
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    String pic = CommonMethod.getRandomString(30);
                    File file = new File(dir, String.valueOf(pic + ".jpg"));
                    picturePath = picturePath + String.valueOf(pic) + ".jpg";
```